# How to correctly execute a python script on the server?

Tags: python, executable, cron-task, shebang

I'm trying to execute my python script on the server. I use a hosting-company that allows me to do cronjobs. when i try to make the server execute the file i always get this error:

```
command /homez.208/thomasdewh/www/denshi/denshi.py must be executable
-- 2014-10-13 10:28:02.687788 exitcode: 255
```

So i found out that i have to use a sheban to tell the server this file can be executed.
So i added:

```
#!/www/python/python
import zipfile
import os.path
import os
import sys
...rest of script...
```

I uploaded this to the file and added all the files that are in C:\Users\my-computer\python27\ to the folder /www/python/python on my webserver via FTP.

But this still dont seem to work.. anybody has an idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: does your server runs linux??

Comment: have you tried: chmod u+x denshi.py

Comment: This seems more like a server configuration problem than a programming problem. I don't think it's a ServerFault question, but maybe a SuperUser question, or one of the Unix-specific sites?

Comment: FYI, of course you are on a unix shared server, just by reading the lines you pasted in your question, I can tell. You do not need to ask for a new unix server, you just need to set the proper permissions as mentioned in my answer. That's really simple.

Comment: My server does not run on linux i think, it's a basic shared server. Does this mean i have to get new hosting and ask for a unix server? Or can i execute that python file inside my normal server?

Answer (score 0):

On a unix system, in order to make a script able to run when invoked, there are 2 things to consider:

1. the shebang `#!...` at the top of the file, this just tells the shell it is executed from, which interpreter to be used during the execution
2. ensure that the file has the executable permission for whoever needs to run it: if is is the current user, then chmod u+x , if it has to be for any member of a given group: chmod g+x , if anobody: chmod a+x

When you do: ls -l, you file must probably be like this:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 apero  staff  0 Oct 14 00:04 script.py
```

If you set u+x (what you must probably do in your case) it becomes:

```
-rwxr--r--  1 apero  staff  0 Oct 14 00:04 script.py
```

if you set g+x it becomes:

```
-rw-r-xr--  1 apero  staff  0 Oct 14 00:04 script.py
```

if you set a+x:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apero  staff  0 Oct 14 00:04 script.py
```

The same can be done for write permissions (w instead of x), and to remove some permission, do the same but with - instead of +.
However, try to never use "a" or "0" as it grants everybody permissions to the file (in read, or write or execute). Btw, whoever can write, can delete, so beware.